# Slide in a popover like UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How do you slide in a popover like the UISplitViewController does in portrait mode?

This has to be a property of popovers now since the UISplitViewController passes back a reference to a popover.  But I can't find anything on popovers that explains how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty confident it's not a popover in the sense of UIPopoverController. It is likely just another view that is presented above the other. I would likely implement this using a container view. The detail view and the side view would both be siblings in the container. The container retains the reference to the side view and slides it in an out at the appropriate time.

Comment: If it isn't a UIPopover then how do you explain the delegate of UISplitView passing back a pointer reference to a popover?

Comment: It seems I very well could be wrong, I assumed they would have changed things around when they went with the slide in approach. UISplitViewControllerDelegate clearly still has some methods that reference a popoverController. I don't think this is a normal use case for UIPopoverController, I assume they did this for backwards compatibility.

Comment: If that is the case, do you think they did some kind of casting?  is that even possible?

Comment: This is all speculation, but it is possible they're ignoring the fact that it is actually a `UIPopoverController` and are grabbing the `contentViewController` property and just sliding its view in. That seems the most likely case to me.